# Firebase DatabaseReference vs DataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I did not quite understand when should I use DatabaseReference and when DataSnapshot.

In my application I seem to be using both of them without real distinction (maybe except for writing to Firebase in which case DataSnapshot was not made for).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DatabaseReference is a starting point for all database operations.  This allows you to read, write, and create new DatabaseReferences.

A DataSnapshot is an efficiently-generated immutable copy of the data at a Firebase Location.  They cannot be modified and will never change.

I believe that under the hood, the DataSnapshot would be a more efficient object to create than a DatabaseReference and a safer object to work with in a read-only scenario as this would be an immutable object without any extra data attached to it like the DatabaseReference.

Sources:

DatabaseReference
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference

DataSnapshot
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot

Comment: So if I understand correctly, basically DatabaseReference is for modifying, adding or removing from Firebase and DataSnapshot is for reading? Is that all there is to it?

Comment: That is how I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

**DatabaseReference** is used to refer to the location of a specific node in your database structure.
**DataSnapshot** is used to fetch data from the node whenever a listener event is triggered from database. The data is fetched in form of key-value pairs.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, basically DatabaseReference is for modifying, adding or removing from Firebase and DataSnapshot is for reading? Is that all there is to it?

Comment: Yes. DataSnapshot can only be used to read data, while you can modify, add, or remove data using DatabaseReference to a specific node AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might still be helpful,

The difference between DatabaseReference and DataSnapShot are clear.
Take **DatabaseReference** as a company that produces all kind of cars, where every types of car are being produced. also take **DataSnapShot** as the General Manager  of the company in which any car purchased by random set of people will have to be cleared by the GM. the GM stands as the DataSnapShot while the Company that produced this types of products is the DatabaseReference.

However in another scenaro, ***DatabaseReference*** is used to Read and Write any form of Data while ***DataSnapShot*** is used to refer to the Data written in the DatabaseReference.