# Firebase List vs Map issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue with Firebase android implementation.
I have a class with HashMap.
When storing the class in Firebase, everything is usually good.
But when the keys of the HashMap are numbers than firebase sometimes mistakes the stored hashmap for a list and throws this exception:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.util.ArrayList

The easiest way to reproduce is to put a single object in the hashmap with the key '1'.

Is there a way around this issue (Besides using keys that Firebase will find appealing)?

Is this a bug in the Firebase implementation?

***EDIT***

Here is the simplest example I have:

```
public void setFirebase(){
    fb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(c.getString(R.string.firebase_base_url));
    fb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ds = dataSnapshot;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

public void writeTestObject(){
    testObject to = new testObject();
    to.testMap =  new HashMap<>();
    to.testMap.put("1","One");
    fb.child("Test").setValue(to);
}

public void readTestObject(){
    testObject res = ds.child("Test").getValue(testObject.class);
}

public void run(){
    setFirebase();
    writeTestObject();
    readTestObject();
}

import java.util.Map;
public class testObject {
    public Map<String, String> testMap;
}
```

The above mentioned exception is thrown on the ***readTestObject()*** function.

Comment: can you show the custom object or your `onDataChanged` function?

Comment: @koceeng added a code example

Comment: It is good and should not create error. But can you show us `testObject` class? I think that will help

Comment: @koceeng my mistake. added it

Comment: wrong source inside `readTestObject()`, it should be `fb.child()` not `ds.child()`

Comment: AFAIK that is incorrect since DatabaseReference does not have a getChild function.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/41369070/565433

Comment: Why don't you move `testObject res = ds.child("Test").getValue(testObject.class);` into inside of `onDataChange` and make `res` accessible?

Comment: It is possible and might be wise, but is irrelevant to the original question and subsequent example. Unless you suggest that this might solve my original problem.

Comment: I think it will. See it like this, you call `readTestObject` directly after `writeTestObject` done, right? but when `writeTestObject` is done, doesn't always mean that `ds` has already filled with data, because Firebase run code inside `onDataChange` asyncronously.

Comment: I've checked. that is not the problem. It might cause other problems of course, but not the one stated above